# The discrete Fourier transform's Gaussian-like eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues, fourier-transform

I have the $N$x$N$ matrix below where $N$ is a power of 2 (usually 64 or 256) and $\omega = 2\pi/N$.  What is its largest eigenvalue?

$\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 2\cos(\omega) & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 2\cos(2\omega) & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2\cos(3\omega) & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2\cos((N-3)\omega) & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 2\cos((N-2)\omega) & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 2\cos((N-1)\omega)
\end{bmatrix}$

This is exactly the $S$ matrix [here](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Eken/Eigenvectors82.pdf) (which explains how this eigenvector is also the simplest eigenvector of the Discrete Fourier Transform); I am wondering if our analysis of this eigenvector has improved since 1982.

For large $N$, I know this eigenvalue tends to 4 and its eigenvector tends to a Gaussian, and I can numerically find the roots of the characteristic polynomial for more precision (e.g., this eigenvalue is 3.903025 for $N$=64), but is there a faster more-accurate method?  Is there a closed-form solution?

To reiterate, the helpful points here are that $N$ is a power of 2 and I am only concerned with the highest eigenvalue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick numerical investigation for $N$ up to 512 leads to a conjectured exact large-$N$ expansion of the largest eigenvalue,
$$
\lambda_0(N) = 4 - \frac{2\pi}{N} + \frac{\pi^2}{2 N^2} - \frac{\pi^3}{24 N^3} + \frac{\pi^4}{48 N^4}
- c_5 \frac{\pi^5}{N^5} + \ldots.
$$
The coefficient $c_5^{-1} = -114.63(1)$ is negative and seems to be a more complicated expression.

**Added 16.07.22, 18:00 CEST**:

Extending the high-precision calculation to $N=1024$, the next two constants seem to be $c_5=-67/(2^6 5!)$ and $c_6=653/(2^7 6!)$. These terms should be verified with a precision higher than 30 digits.

**Edited 17.07.22, 15:00 CEST:**

I did this verification with 100 digits precision, verifying $c_{5,6}$ and extending the series to 10th order.
Therefore,
$$
\lambda_0(N) = 4 - \frac{2\pi}{N} 
+ \frac{\pi^2}{2 N^2} 
- \frac{\pi^3}{24 N^3} 
+ \frac{\pi^4}{48 N^4}
+ \frac{67\pi^5}{7680 N^5} 
+ \frac{653\pi^6}{92160 N^6}
+\frac{32519 \pi ^7}{5160960 N^7}
+\frac{135001 \pi ^8}{20643840 N^8}
+\frac{45750727 \pi ^9}{5945425920 N^9}
+\frac{1198585643 \pi ^{10}}{118908518400 N^{10}}
+\ldots.
$$
Note that the denominators of $c_n$ are divisible by $n!$.

All constants were successively determined by a least-square fit of a 20th order polynomial in $\pi/N$ to $λ_0(N)$. I did not find a known function with this series expansion.

For reference, I'll append the 30 digits results:
\begin{array}{ll}
N & λ_0(N)\\
 128 & 3.95121320281088603898478521135 \\
 256 & 3.97553152996970070083424756460 \\
 384 & 3.98367098180919839228844082991 \\
 512 & 3.98774696887736782094115794509 \\
 640 & 3.99019456589827273460033342852 \\
 768 & 3.99182713285240169577614505117 \\
 896 & 3.99299366147114034625800714548 \\
 1024 & 3.99386878184121881247367446866 \\
\end{array}

Comment: Wow!  But, my instinct is that $c_5$ should be rational and the "..." part would then have bigger (also rational) coefficients to account for the difference.  Aren't you simply forcing the "..." to zero for your "high-precision results"?

Comment: No, I still allow for higher order terms, see my updated answer.

Comment: I am kind of surprised that the low-order c coefficients do not find a more-precise fit. It is as if they were forced to be of the rational form 2/A (where A is an integer). Anyway, as a more thorough check, I wonder how nice the coefficients would look if you expand using a 10th order polynomial in e/N or sqrt(2)/N (or any other famous irrational constant).

Comment: The fit gives the exact expansion (at least up to $c_4$) of $\lambda_0(N)$ around $N=\infty$. This expansion obviously has simple rational coefficients in $\pi/N$. One could also rewrite the expansion in terms of $\omega=2\pi/N$, and get a rational expansion in $\omega$ around $\omega=0$.

Comment: With 100 digits precision, I got some more terms, $$ \ldots +\frac{32519 \pi ^7}{5160960 N^7} + \frac{135001 \pi ^8}{20643840 N^8} + \frac{45750727 \pi ^9}{5945425920 N^9} + \frac{1198585643 \pi ^{10}}{118908518400 N^{10}} + \ldots . $$

Comment: Any simple explanation for why $c_1$ appears to be exactly 2?  or, if that is easy, why $c_2$ appears to be exactly 1/2?  I think that these two terms should just come from the first and second derivatives (with respect to $\omega$) of your best numerical $\lambda$ table.

Comment: The first order correction $c_1$ can be obtained by first order perturbation theory. For $N\to\infty$, the leading eigenvector $|v_0^{(1)}\rangle$ is Gaussian, with width $\sigma^2=N/(2\pi)$, while in 0th order $\lambda_0^{(0)}=4$ and $|v_0^{(0)}\rangle=\{1,0,0,\ldots\}$. Therefore, we have $$ S |v_0^{(1)}\rangle = \lambda_0^{(1)} |v_0^{(1)}\rangle + \mathcal{O}(N^{-2}).$$ This gives $\lambda_0^{(1)}=4-2\pi/N+\pi^2/N^2+\ldots$, which is correct to first order. Higher orders are more involved.