# Eigenvalues invariant under 90° rotation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

Consider $N \times N$ matrices

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
0      & 0 & \cdots  & 0     & 1     \\
1    & 0     & 0 &         & 0    \\
\vdots   & 1    & 0    & \ddots  & \vdots  \\
0  &         & \ddots  & \ddots  & 0 \\
0  & 0 & \cdots  &1    & 0     \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
and

$$B=\operatorname{diag}( \cos(2\pi\cdot 0/N),...,\cos(2\pi\cdot (N-1)/N)).$$

Does anybody know why the eigenvalues of $i(A+A^T)+2B$ are invariant under 90° rotations?- Numerics seem to imply this. What I mean by this is that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then also $e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}} \lambda.$

Comment: This property of the eigenvalues does not seem to hold for $N=2$, $N=3$ or $N=4$ (I haven't tried any higher). Of course, for $N=2$ or $N=3$, this can only be true if all eigenvalues are zero (but they aren't). For $N=4$, I had some hope, but alas, no: The eigenvalues are $i\sqrt{3} $, $-i\sqrt{3} $, $0$, $0$.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt sorry there was a 2 missing in front of $B$, now it should be fine.

Comment: Related? 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426279

Comment: The new factor 2 in front of $B$ makes things rather more pathological: For $N=2$ and $N=4$, the matrices now are deficient, consisting of $2\times 2$ Jordan blocks, all with eigenvalue 0; so yes, in a trivial sense, you could say that, if 0 is an eigenvalue, also $e^{i\pi /2} 0$ is an eigenvalue. For $N=3$, the eigenvalues are nonzero, and the claimed property doesn't (and can't) hold.

Comment: @FredHucht - if it weren't for that factor $i$ in front of $A+A^T $, which completely changes things ... but if we leave out the factor $i$, the matrix is Hermitean, and the eigenvalues real, so the claimed property again can't arise ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $N$ is even (this is false when N is odd).
Let $X=2B, Y=A+A^T$.
Let
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1    & \zeta     & \zeta^2 & \cdots & \zeta^{N-1} \\
1    & \zeta^2     & \zeta^4 & \cdots & \zeta^{2(N-1)} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots \\
1  & \zeta^{N-1} &  \zeta^{2(N-1)} & \cdots & \zeta^{(N-1)^2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$Q = \text{diag}(1, -1, 1, -1, \ldots, 1, -1)$$
where $\zeta=e^{\frac{2i\pi}{N}}$.

One can easily check that
$$PXP^{-1}=Y$$
$$PYP^{-1}=X$$
$$QXQ^{-1}=X$$
$$QYQ^{-1}=-Y$$
from which it follows that
$$P(X+iY)P^{-1}=Y+iX=i(X-iY)$$
$$Q(X+iY)Q^{-1}=X-iY$$
This shows that $X+iY$ is conjugate to $i(X+iY)$, so its eigenvalues are invariant under multiplication by $i$.